# IE8 issue with container?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

Having an issue where internet explorer causes the container of my website to look stretched out:

[image]

the url for the site is http://profiledt.co.uk/SetTraining/

I understand that IE8 isn't supported by many sites now but i feel that having the site container fixed would reduce the bounce rating.

Thanks

Comment: what is the exact problem?

Comment: what is your priblem/

Comment: It clearly states above. "Having an issue where internet explorer causes the container of my website to look stretched out:"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the [-ms-filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530752%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property to your slides.

Example:

```
<li id="ts-twentytwelve-slide-5272327b9a2a3823180679" class="ts-twentytwelve-slide  cycle-slide" style="background-image: url(http://profiledt.co.uk/SetTraining/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/dreamstime_l_26128127.jpg); position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 97; display: none; opacity: 0;filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='http://profiledt.co.uk/SetTraining/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/dreamstime_l_26128127.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');-ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='http://profiledt.co.uk/SetTraining/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/dreamstime_l_26128127.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')">
    <a href="" class="ts-twentytwelve-link " style="left: 540px; top: 191px">
        <div class="ts-twentytwelve-overlay">
            <h1 class="ts-twentytwelve-title">Slider too big?</h1>
            <p class="ts-twentytwelve-description">Slider too big?</p>
        </div>
    </a>
</li>
```

Replace the `src` for each image individually.
It forces to scale the background image up to its container dimensions.

**EDIT**

According to your comment you could try this (I've not tested it):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.ts-twentytwelve li').each(function(){
        var bg = $(this).css('background-image');
        bg = bg.replace('url("','').replace('")','');

        $(this).css({
            "filter": "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='"+bg+"', sizingMethod='scale')",
            "-ms-filter" : "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='"+bg+"', sizingMethod='scale')"
        });             
    });
});
</script>
```

It loops through each slide and adds the filters with the specific background image.
And as shadow wizard mentioned add a valid doctype to your document (download the header.php and check if the top looks like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * some comments here...
 */
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 7]>
<html class="ie ie7" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html class="ie ie8" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 7) | !(IE 8)  ]><!-->
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Hi Damian, the problem with this is that the slider is a plugin and I can't access each image individually?

Comment: Thanks Damian, Sorry to sound like an idiot, where exactly would I place this? Would you be able to give me the file I need to edit? 

Thanks

Comment: I see you're using wordpress (with the twentytwelve theme) so try accessing your site through FTP and change the directory to `wp-content` -> `themes` -> `twentytwelve` and download the file `footer.php`. Afterwards insert the `jQuery code` above after `<?php wp_footer(); ?>` but before `</body>`

Comment: Thanks Damian, I believe I have it added. Will test.

Answer (score 3):

The reason this is happening is most likely IE falling into quirks mode. IE8 falls down to IE5 quirks mode, which obviously can't be a good thing.

The reason for this is totally invalid HTML you have.

Your document starts with those two lines:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Baumans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Followed by the `<!DOCTYPE html>` and the rest. Put those lines in the proper place and validate your HTML using some tool, e.g. [this one](http://html5.validator.nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fprofiledt.co.uk%2FSetTraining%2F). ([official validator](http://validator.w3.org) is down for some reason, probably too many people used it)

Comment: +1. Always put the doctype first to avoid major rendering issues.

Comment: Thanks Shadow, Going through and fixing with the validator